# Unresolved reference runTransaction Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need to check for stock in certain products and I need to run a transaction to be sure that this operation is unique and there is not other users decreasing this at the same time

but when I try to run a transaction like

```
 FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("shops").document(shopId).runTransaction
```

it tells me that `runTransaction` is not resolved...

From the documentation its applied to a document

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`runTransaction()` is not a method on [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference).  It's [a method on FirebaseFirestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FirebaseFirestore#runTransaction(com.google.firebase.firestore.Transaction.Function%3CTResult%3E)).

In your transaction handler function, you have to identify the documents you want to participate in the transaction using the [Transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Transaction) object provided to the function handler.

Comment: can you elaborate with the code I provide to run the transaction on the shop document ?

Comment: There's not much else to say - the examples in the documentation are accurate.

Comment: ok thanks, maybe sometimes is easier for us that we are just starting to see it in code than just linking to the methods declaration itself, I know is a simple thing, I have now understood it but sometimes just a few links does not solve the problem, thanks doug